# Как в PaperClip установить изображение по умолчанию?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель пользователя:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
                    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Код во views:

```
<p>
    <strong>Avatar:</strong> <br>
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
</p>
```

Делал все по документации https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
Если у пользователя нет аватарки, то она не отображается. В папке /assets/images имеется изображение missing.png, но на выходе получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается ошибка в примере разработчика?

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Решение данной проблемы описано здесь: http://www.suffix.be/blog/default-image-paperclip Рад, если помог кому-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что одним missing.png файлом вам не обойтись, вы должны создать под каждый стиль свой missing-файл (при условии, что вы не переопределяете механизм поиска missing-файлов). Т.е. если вы используете стиль :medium, по умолчанию PaperClip будет искать его по пути assets/images/medium/missing.png, если вы захотите использовать стиль :thumb для него тоже нужно заготовить изображение assets/images/thumb/missing.png.

Стили разные, размер у них разные, поэтому и изображения тоже разные. Для того, чтобы сориентироваться где PaperClip ожидает увидеть изображение, просто создайте пользователя без аватрки в Rails консоли и посмотрите URL изображения

```
user = User.last
user.avatar.url(:medium)
"/images/medium/missing.png"
```

Comment: спасибо, я уже нашел решение http://www.suffix.be/blog/default-image-paperclip . Аналогиное тому, что Вы говорите